# how to set up multiple function in an Object prototype

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do you set up an Object that has multiple functions the second code example is what I'm trying todo

```
Object.defineProperty(NodeList.prototype, 'each', {
    value: function (fn) {
        return Array.from(this).forEach((node, index) => fn(node, index))
    }
});
```

// below doesn't work

```
HTMLElement.prototype = {
   hasClass: function(selector) {
   },
   next: function(selector) {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Object.assign` instead:

```js
Object.assign(HTMLElement.prototype, {
  hasClass(selector) {
    return this.classList.contains(selector);
  },
  next(selector) {
    const { nextElementSibling } = this;
    return nextElementSibling && nextElementSibling.matches(selector)
    ? nextElementSibling
    : null;
  }
});

const div = document.querySelector('div');
console.log(div.hasClass('foo'));
console.log(div.next('div'));
```

```html
<div class="foo"></div>
```

(that said, note that mutating the built-in prototypes is not very good practice, and can result in problems, especially when you start including other scripts on your page - better to define standalone functions, or to make your own wrapper around elements that has such methods)

You could also use [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) to define multiple properties at once, but the code required is more long-winded.

Comment: When you say mutating built-in prototype is not good practice and can result in problems like including other scripts what kind of problems do you mean. I'm building my own javascript library based of HTMLElement - what would you do

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice . If you're making a library, consider using a wrapper around the elements instead, like I suggested - then, calling your custom functions on wrapped elements will work, without having to change the built-in behavior.

Comment: Can you make me an example of what a wrapper is when making a library

Comment: For example, remember how we had to back out of the `Array.prototype.flatten` proposal because a *very few* old websites using MooTools had added their own custom `Array.prototype.flatten` methods to the prototype, thereby breaking their sites? As a result we got sillyness like [this](https://github.com/staltz/prevent-smoosh). Best to avoid causing problems like that, by not mutating built-in prototypes

Comment: You can make a class which you can call with an HTMLElement. Then just put methods on the class, instead of on HTMLElement.prototype.