# how do you create a wrapper object that acts as a function like jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't know where to start but what I want or need is a wrapper function for HTMLElement so I don't extend HTMLElement class but etend my own object and then check has class to see if the element has a class etc etc but my code doesn't work at all it says $(...).hasClass is not a function

```
$ = function(a, b) {
  this.$el = document.querySelector(a);
  return this;
}

Object.assign($.prototype, {
  hasClass: function(selector) {
    return this.$el.classList.contains(selector);
  }
})

console.log($('#list').hasClass('list'));
```

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there - the issue is that the standalone expression

```
$('#list')
```

will have the default calling context of `window` (the `this` value inside the `$` function). If you want to create an instance which can use prototype methods, put `new` before the call to `$`:

```js
const $ = function(a, b) {
  this.$el = document.querySelector(a);
}

Object.assign($.prototype, {
  hasClass: function(selector) {
    return this.$el.classList.contains(selector);
  }
})

console.log(new $('#list').hasClass('list'));
console.log(new $('#list2').hasClass('foo'));
```

```html
<div id="list"></div>
<div id="list2" class="foo"></div>
```

If you don't want to put `new` before every call, you can use `Object.create` inside `$`:

```js
const $ = function(a, b) {
  const $obj = Object.create(proto);
  $obj.$el = document.querySelector(a);
  return $obj;
}

const proto = {
  hasClass: function(selector) {
    return this.$el.classList.contains(selector);
  }
};

console.log($('#list').hasClass('list'));
console.log($('#list2').hasClass('foo'));
```

```html
<div id="list"></div>
<div id="list2" class="foo"></div>
```

I think the way jQuery does it is, the returned object's internal prototype is `$.fn`, eg:

```js
const $ = function(a, b) {
  const $obj = Object.create($.fn);
  $obj.$el = document.querySelector(a);
  return $obj;
};
$.fn = {
  hasClass: function(selector) {
    return this.$el.classList.contains(selector);
  }
};

console.log($('#list').hasClass('list'));
console.log($('#list2').hasClass('foo'));
```

```html
<div id="list"></div>
<div id="list2" class="foo"></div>
```

Comment: Ok cool but I don't want to hacve to pu the keyword "new" infront of $('') everytime so whats the work around for that

Comment: Use `Object.create`, as in the second snippet

Comment: it says proto is undefined

Comment: Press the "Run code snippet" button in the answer to see it in action - it works just fine here. Are you sure you defined `proto` in your code?

Comment: One of my points was to use Object.assign($.prototype, {}); and now you've taken it away

Comment: You don't have to `Object.assign` to anything with this method, you can simply define the prototype object outright - there's nothing wrong with that, in fact, it's probably preferable. Mutation is best avoided when not necessary, in most cases.

Comment: Thank you for your help today, you have been teaching me new things

Comment: The [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55681764/how-to-set-up-multiple-function-in-an-object-prototype/55681787#55681787) *required* `Object.assign` (or something like it that involved mutation) because you *had* to mutate an existing object, `HTMLElement.prototype`, but here, since you're creating the prototype yourself, you can just declare that prototype.

Comment: I used backbone a while back and when rendering the node backbone had the property "el" so you would call myelement.render().el and there was also the jquery "$el" in the chain I'm confused to what's what, do you know which is which so I can store that information correctly

Comment: The returned object's `$el` property will reference the selected element (if any), eg `$('#list').$el` will work in any of the snippets, if that's what you're looking for. As you can see by running them, there's no need to do that if you're just trying to call one of the prototype methods

Answer (score 1):

Alternate Method do with return function inside the function

```js
const $ = function(a, b) {
  var elem = document.querySelector(a);
  return {
    hasClass: function(selector) {
      return elem.classList.contains(selector);
    },
    addClass:function(cls){
      elem.classList.add(cls)
    }
  }
};

console.log($('#list').hasClass('list'));
console.log($('#list2').hasClass('foo'));
$('#list2').addClass('color_red');
```

```css
.color_red{
  color:red
}
```

```html
<div id="list"></div>
<div id="list2" class="foo">hello</div>
```